# Detect ScrollView has reached the end

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I have a `Text` with long text inside a `ScrollView` and I want to detect when the user has scrolled to the end of the text so I can enable a button.

I've been debugging the event object from the `onScroll` event but there doesn't seem any value I can use.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

I did it like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {ScrollView, Text} from 'react-native';
    
const isCloseToBottom = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
  const paddingToBottom = 20;
  return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
    contentSize.height - paddingToBottom;
};
    
const MyCoolScrollViewComponent = ({enableSomeButton}) => (
  <ScrollView
    onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
      if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
        enableSomeButton();
      }
    }}
    scrollEventThrottle={400}
  >
    <Text>Here is very long lorem ipsum or something...</Text>
  </ScrollView>
);
    
export default MyCoolScrollViewComponent;
```

I wanted to add `paddingToBottom` because usually it is not needed that ScrollView is scrolled to the bottom till last pixel. But if you want that set paddingToBottom to zero.

Comment: Note that if your content is shorter than the container, then this will trigger always. If you have a case where your paddingToBottom is negative (e.g. for handling overscroll), then make sure to handle this situation separately (basically by `contentOffset.y > -paddingToBottom` (note the resulting double negative))

Comment: This is not triggering "always" for me. `onScroll` only is called when the user scrolls.

Comment: in scroll end it is working perfect but when I scroll up from last ending point then it called. So any solution to stop this issue when scroll up?

Comment: I had that same problem, on IOS it worked great but android was glitchy. Try using `onMomentumScrollEnd` instead which calls an event every time the scroll stops.

Comment: Note that the parameters are destructured twice in his example. It's prone to making mistake.

Comment: I have implemented the above code and it worked for both iOS and Android, but it is not working on my web browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 48):

As people helped here I will add the simple code they write to make reached to top and reached to bottom event and I did a little illustration to make things simpler

[image: Layout and vars values]

```
<ScrollView
onScroll={({nativeEvent})=>{
if(isCloseToTop(nativeEvent)){
    //do something
}
if(isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)){
   //do something
}
}}
>
...contents
</ScrollView>



isCloseToBottom({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}){
   return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - 20;
}



ifCloseToTop({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}){
   return contentOffset.y == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

```
<... onScroll={(e) => {
        let paddingToBottom = 10;
        paddingToBottom += e.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height;
        if(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y >= e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height - paddingToBottom) {
          // make something...
        }
      }}>...
```

like this react-native 0.44

Answer (score 7):

For Horizontal ScrollView (e.g. Carousels) replace `isCloseToBottom` function with `isCloseToRight`

```
isCloseToRight = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
    const paddingToRight = 20;
    return layoutMeasurement.width + contentOffset.x >= contentSize.width - paddingToRight;
};
```

Comment: how about close to left? is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Another solution could be to use a `ListView` with a single row (your text) which has `onEndReached` method. See the documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#onendreached)

Comment: But this would require that each paragraph of the text to be treated with a DataSource and create a component (a simple Text would do). Not a bad idea, but might be a little bit more complex to implement.

Comment: Your `onEndReached` has saved me a lot of time.

Comment: ListView is deprecated.  

https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html

Answer (score 5):

@Henrik R's right.
But you should use Math.ceil() too.

```
function handleInfinityScroll(event) {
        let mHeight = event.nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.height;
        let cSize = event.nativeEvent.contentSize.height;
        let Y = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;

        if(Math.ceil(mHeight + Y) >= cSize) return true;
        return false;
}
```

[image]

Comment: why should you use the Ceil?

Answer (score 5):

```
const isCloseToBottom = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
const paddingToBottom = 120
return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - paddingToBottom}


 <ScrollView
    onMomentumScrollEnd={({ nativeEvent }) => {
      if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
        loadMoreData()
      }
    }}
    scrollEventThrottle={1}
  >
```

Above answer is correct but to **callback on reaching the end in scrollView** use **onMomentumScrollEnd** not **onScroll**

Comment: you should remove that async keyword, it's useless, and because of that the isCloseToBottom result will always be detected as true

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the answer of Henrik R:

If you need to know wether the user has reached the end of the content at mount time (if the content may or may not be too long, depending on device size) - here is my solution:

```
<ScrollView 
        onLayout={this.onLayoutScrollView}
        onScroll={this.onScroll}>
    <View onLayout={this.onLayoutScrollContent}>
        {/*...*/}
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

in combination with

```
onLayout(wrapper, { nativeEvent }) {
    if (wrapper) {
        this.setState({
            wrapperHeight: nativeEvent.layout.height,
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            contentHeight: nativeEvent.layout.height,
            isCloseToBottom:
              this.state.wrapperHeight - nativeEvent.layout.height >= 0,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use ScrollView and this worked for me

Here is my solution:

I passed onMomentumScrollEnd prop to scrollView and on the basis event.nativeEvent I achieved onEndReached functionality in ScrollView

```
 onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => { 
          if (isCloseToBottom(event.nativeEvent)) {
            LoadMoreRandomData()
          }
         }
       }}

  const isCloseToBottom = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
const paddingToBottom = 20;
return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
  contentSize.height - paddingToBottom;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function `onMomentumScrollEnd` to know  scroll information (event)

```
<ScrollView onMomentumScrollEnd={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                handleScroll(nativeEvent)
            }}>
```

and with these measure `(layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - paddingToBottom)`

you can know if the scroll is at the end

```
const handleScroll = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
        const paddingToBottom = 20;
        if (layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - paddingToBottom) {
            ...
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

disregard all convoluted answers above. this works.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

function Component() {
  const [momentum, setMomentum] = useState(false)

  return (
    <ScrollView
    onMomentumScrollBegin={() => setMomentum(true)}
    onEndReached={momentum === true ? console.log('end reached.') : null}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0}
    >
      <Text>Filler Text 01</Text>
      <Text>Filler Text 02</Text>
      <Text>Filler Text 03</Text>
      <Text>Filler Text 04</Text>
      <Text>Filler Text 05</Text>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Comment: When I try this I get an error that property onEndReached does not exist on ScrollView