# React Native ScrollView with a FlatList

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

My main component view is a ScrollView which has many views and a component which renders a flatlist.
The thing is I want to scroll down the screen and when it reaches the end, where is the flatlist, start scrolling the flatlist. How can I achieve this?

I have something like this:

```
<ScrollView>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <Image>
                <View>  
                    <Text></Text>
                    <Text></Text>
                </View>
            </Image>
            <EventInfo/>
            <Text>  </Text>
            <Text>  </Text>
            <EventHeader/>
        </View>
        <EventGuests/>
</ScrollView>
```

EventGuests is the component which renders the flatlist.
This way is shown the entire list and all the screen is scrolled.

Answer (score 7):

The best approach to do this is to use ListHeaderComponent prop of FlatList.

[You can check it here.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/flatlist.html#listheadercomponent)

Just pass your all your components which are higher than FlatList into FlatList header prop.
This is right approach to have no conflict between ScrollView and FlatList scrolling.

Comment: Issue will arise once you try to call scroll methods, since `HeaderComponent` will have unpredictable height. hence  `getItemLayout ` will not be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `onScroll` props in your `ScrollView` component. We can use it to detect end of the scrolled screen.

```
const isReachedEnd = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
  const paddingToBottom = 10;

  return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - paddingToBottom;
};

const renderEventGuests = () => {
  return (
    <EventGuests />
  );
};

render() {
  return (
    <ScrollView
      onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
        if (this.isReachedEnd(nativeEvent)) {
          this.renderEventGuests();
        }
      }}
      scrollEventThrottle={400} 
    >
      <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
        <Image>
          <View>  
            <Text></Text>
            <Text></Text>
          </View>
        </Image>

        <EventInfo />

        <Text></Text>
        <Text></Text>

        <EventHeader />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Ref: [Detect ScrollView has reached the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056761/detect-scrollview-has-reached-the-end)

Comment: Didn't work. But already solved it: the image was breaking everything. Don't know why

Comment: @thomas12 can you please share how you end up solving it?