# How to determine end of the scrollView React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I need to determine if the srollView has reached to the end. If it is I need call a function. How can I do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect ScrollView has reached the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056761/detect-scrollview-has-reached-the-end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after some digging I found

[Detect ScrollView has reached the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056761/detect-scrollview-has-reached-the-end)

It is working like a charm.