# How check if user scrolled to top in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm facing an issue in which I need to change header text position from left to centre when user begin scroll and back to left if user scroll to top. But I unable to find solution for. I'm using scrollview which have a lot of content inside it. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: You can use `onScroll` in your ScrollView. It provides this props `{nativeEvent: {contentInset: {bottom, left, right, top},contentOffset: {x, y},contentSize: {height, width},layoutMeasurement: {height, width},zoomScale}}`. You can use contentOffset for your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a solution here :

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056761/detect-scrollview-has-reached-the-end#:%7E:text=As%20people%20helped%20here%20I%20will%20add%20the%20simple%20code%20they%20write%20to%20make%20reached%20to%20top%20and%20reached%20to%20bottom%20event%20and%20I%20did%20a%20little%20illustration%20to%20make%20things%20simpler)

```
    <ScrollView
onScroll={({nativeEvent})=>{
if(isCloseToTop(nativeEvent)){
    //do something
}
if(isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)){
   //do something
}
}}
>
...contents
</ScrollView>



isCloseToBottom({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}){
   return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - 20;
}



ifCloseToTop({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}){
   return contentOffset.y == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Example() {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(-1);

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("scrollPosition: ", scrollPosition);

    if (scrollPosition === 0) {
      // condition is true when scroll on top
    }
  }, [scrollPosition]);

  const getscrollposition = (e) => {
    const y = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    setScrollPosition(y);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView
      onMomentumScrollEnd={getscrollposition}
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
    >
      .....
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```