# Callback for scrollToEnd in ScrollView

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am looking for a way to have a callback called after scrollToEnd has reached the end of my ScrollView. The animated scrolling begins when i click a button and when end is reached i want to call some other actions.

I have looked over the documentation but it seems no callback is implemented by default?

My code below

```
scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
// WHEN DONE i have some actions here that i want to trigger when animated scroll has reached the end       

<ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }} >
  //Content here
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056761/detect-scrollview-has-reached-the-end

Comment: I found that aswell but i dont want to trigger it everytime the scroll reaches the bottom, only when the animated scroll fires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a state in onscroll callback for checking is it called by default or its called when you fires the scroll function

```
const [isScrollByMe,setIsScrollByMe] =  React.useState(false);
const [isScrollViewAtEnd,setIsScrollViewAtEnd] =  React.useState(false);
```

set state before calling scrollToEnd

```
if(isScrollViewAtEnd) {
 //perform your action
  
} else {
  setIsScrollByMe(true);
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true});
}
```

then check the state in onScroll callback

```
const isCloseToBottom = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
  const paddingToBottom = 20;
  return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
    contentSize.height - paddingToBottom;
};
...
onScroll={({nativeEvent}) => {
      if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
          setIsScrollViewAtEnd(true)
        if(isScrollByMe) {
           setIsScrollByMe(false); // for not calling by default
          //perform your action  
           }
        } else { 
        setIsScrollViewAtEnd(false)               
      } 
}
```

Check if this solution worked for you.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks alot man! Just one thing though. If i am already scrolled to the bottom and click the button it seems that the actions do not fire. Is there any way to check if it is already scrolled to the end and if that is the case just call the actions and dont set the state?

Comment: Please check I updated the answer. is this will work?

Comment: Amazing! It really works out of the box! Thanks alot man! :D