# Update Props if components are defined in a static array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to update the props data in the component. It's just that these components were previously defined via Array objects. Here's my code:

```
const [isLoadMore, setIsLoadMore] = useState(false)
const animeInfoTab = [
        {
            id: 1,
            label: Message.overview,
            value: Message.overview,
            content: null
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            label: Message.character,
            value: Message.character,
            content: <CharacterPage animeid={animeId} />
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            label: Message.discussion,
            value: Message.discussion,
            content: <DiscussionPage animeid={animeId} isMore={isLoadMore} />
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            label: Message.rating,
            value: Message.rating,
            content: <RatingPage animeid={animeId} />
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            label: Message.myrating,
            value: Message.myrating,
            content: <MyRatingPage animeid={animeId} />
        }
    ]

return (
 <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} onScroll={(e) => onScrollBottom(e.nativeEvent) ? setIsLoadMore(true) : null}>
{animeInfoTab[2].content}
</ScrollView>
)
```

Here I want to update the isLoadMore state to true when the scroll reaches the bottom. However, the <DiscussionPage> component still doesn't change. What should I do?

Comment: maybe, you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056761/detect-scrollview-has-reached-the-end